# Typescript type inference does not work with function type guards

Tags: typescript

In `alpha` I check whether the result is `null` and `throw new Error` if so, but the comiler still shows a compilation error:

```
 const obj = {
  objMethod: function (): string | null {
    return 'always a string';
  },
};

function alpha() {
  if (obj.objMethod() === null) {
    throw new Error('type guard, but compiler does not count it as one :( ');
  }

  const beta: string = obj.objMethod();
  console.log(beta);
}
```

But this code works perfectly well:

```
const obj = {
  objMethod: function (): string | null {
    return 'always a string';
  },
};

function alpha() {
  const result = obj.objMethod();
  if (result === null) {
    throw new Error('this DOES count as a type guard. ');
  }

  const beta: string = result; // no error
  console.log(beta);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript cannot prove that your `objMethod` will always return the same value. It could return a non-null value at the first call, and null at the second. If you assign it to a const variable, the check asserts that the variable is not null. Since the variable is const, the value cannot change after the assignment, thus, it must be non-null if it passed the check.